# Error with gtest installation on home system

Tags: c++, makefile, libraries, googletest, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im trying to setup my home computer the same way as the computers at my school so I can work on my assignments from here, but I can't for the life of me get gtest working correctly. I've run through the recommended install process and figured out that it needs the ".so" libraries to not throw 'pthread' not found errors.

Makefile:

```
PROJECT_DIR = Electra
PROGRAM_TEST = testProject

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

LINKFLAGS = -lgtest

SRC_DIR = src

TEST_DIR = test

SRC_INCLUDE = include
INCLUDE = -I ${SRC_INCLUDE}

GCOV = gcov
LCOV = lcov
COVERAGE_RESULTS = results.coverage
COVERAGE_DIR = docs/code/coverage

STATIC_ANALYSIS = cppcheck

STYLE_CHECK = cpplint.py

DOXY_DIR = docs/code

#Targets
#
#.PHONY: all
#all: $(PROGRAM_TEST) memcheck coverage docs static style

#Temporary all target. use ^^^ this one once docs and coverage required
.PHONY: all
all: $(PROGRAM_TEST) memcheck static style

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf *~ $(SRC)/*.o $(TEST_DIR)/output/*.dat \
        *.gcov *.gcda *.gcno *.orig ???*/*.orig \
        *.bak ???*/*.bak $(PROGRAM_GAME) \
        ???*/*~ ???*/???*/*~ $(COVERAGE_RESULTS) \
        $(PROGRAM_TEST) $(MEMCHECK_RESULTS) $(COVERAGE_DIR)  \
        $(DOXY_DIR)/html obj bin

$(PROGRAM_TEST): $(TEST_DIR) $(SRC_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM_TEST) $(INCLUDE) \
        $(TEST_DIR)/*.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp $(LINKFLAGS)

tests: $(PROGRAM_TEST)
    $(PROGRAM_TEST)

memcheck: $(PROGRAM_TEST)
    valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes $(PROGRAM_TEST)

fullmemcheck: $(PROGRAM_TEST)
    valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full $(PROGRAM_TEST)

coverage: $(PROGRAM_TEST)
    $(PROGRAM_TEST)
        # Determine code coverage
    $(LCOV) --capture --gcov-tool $(GCOV) --directory . --output-file $(COVERAGE_RESULTS)
        # Only show code coverage for the source code files (not library files)
    $(LCOV) --extract $(COVERAGE_RESULTS) */$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/* -o $(COVERAGE_RESULTS)
        #Generate the HTML reports
    genhtml $(COVERAGE_RESULTS) --output-directory $(COVERAGE_DIR)
        #Remove all of the generated files from gcov
    rm -f *.gcda *.gcno

static: ${SRC_DIR} ${TEST_DIR}
    ${STATIC_ANALYSIS} --verbose --enable=all ${SRC_DIR} ${TEST_DIR} ${SRC_INCLUDE} --suppress=missingInclude

style: ${SRC_DIR} ${TEST_DIR} ${SRC_INCLUDE}
    ${STYLE_CHECK} $(SRC_INCLUDE)/* ${SRC_DIR}/* ${TEST_DIR}/*

#.PHONY: docs
#docs: ${SRC_INCLUDE}
#        doxygen $(DOXY_DIR)/doxyfile
```

Running "make tests" results in the following

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -o testProject -I include \
        test/*.cpp src/*.cpp -lgtest
testProject
make: testProject: Command not found
Makefile:53: recipe for target 'tests' failed
make: *** [tests] Error 127
```

Any idea as to why this wont work? Or how to even get started trying to resolve this? Its not a very detailed error. I don't want to change the Makefile, as it works for my school systems and this is a shared project.

My home system is running Windows 10, and im using the Ubuntu shell to run makefiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POSIX shells the current working directory is not searched by default.  This is a safety measure that comes from POSIX's origins as a multi-user system: you don't want someone to be able to drop a program like `ls` in some directory and have unsuspecting people run it just by typing `ls` in that directory.

Apparently in your school systems, someone has added the current working directory (`.`) to your `PATH` environment variable, while at home you do not have it added.

Your makefile is wrong, the recipe should be:

```
tests: $(PROGRAM_TEST)
        ./$(PROGRAM_TEST)
```

to force the program from the current working directory to be run, instead of relying on the cwd appearing in the `PATH` (or running some other instance of `testProgram` that does happen to be on your `PATH`).

This will work on all your systems.

Comment: Thanks a ton! How would I go about adding the ./ to my PATH variable?

Comment: You shouldn't do that for the reason I mentioned (it's a security hole) as well as other reasons, such as you shouldn't write a makefile that won't work unless the person using it has configured their environment in a specific way.  If you do still want to do it, you should investigate documentation for your shell and find out where the shell setup files live and what their called, then you can modify your `PATH` environment variable in one of those files.